# What is the best practice for managing Java 8 streams with multiple results

Tags: java, collections, foreach, java-8, java-stream

How to process forEach in Java 8 using streams when I want to have multiple results from the iteration. Of course calling List.add method in stream forEach operation is not an option... How would you rewrite this code using Java 8 streams?

```
additionalWebsitesList = Lists.newArrayList();
String additionalWebistesCsv = "";
for (String website : additionalWebsites) {
    WebsiteModel websiteModel = getWebsiteModel(website);

    //How this can be processed via Stream???
    additionalWebsitesList.add(websiteModel);
    areaModels.addAll(websiteModel.getAreas());
    additionalWebistesCsv += websiteModel.getId();
}
```

Comment: why would you want to, just keep the code as is.

Comment: I wouldn't. And what is `areaModels`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best practice for managing Java 8 streams with multiple
>   results
>
> Of course calling List.add method in stream forEach operation is not
>   an option.

The best practice is not forcing you to use streams as the use case is not appropriate.
The `Stream` interface javadoc describes itself as :

> A sequence of elements supporting sequential and parallel aggregate
>   operations.

`Stream` operations return themselves a sequence of typed elements.
So `Stream` collects will return finally a single kind of thing based on the type of the sequence of elements : unitary or a collection of.
We could for example collect a `Foo`, a `List` of `Foo`, a `Map` of `Foo` indexed by `Integer` keys, and so for...
`Stream` collects are not designed to collect different custom things such as a `List` of `Foo` + a `List` of `Bar` + the count of `Bar` + `Foo`.

As @Eugene underlined, Streams also provide a way to get [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) that is a set of things : common aggregates that are minimum, maximum, sum, and average. 
But should we not consider that it collects finally a single thing : statistics ?

So you have three ways :

- putting aside `Stream` for your use case and keeping the `for` loop.
- using multiple streams : one stream by custom thing that you want to collect.
- using a single stream with a custom collector.

I would not use the second way in any case as it will produce a less readable and straight code that your actual.

About the last way (custom collector) illustrated by the Federico Peralta Schaffner answer. It is straighter and it allows to benefit from stream parallelism. So it is an option to consider.
But it also requires more boiler plate code and has more reading indirection to understand the actual logic.
So I think that I would introduce a custom collector only in two cases :

- the collector is reused.
- we want to benefit from the stream parallelism **and** we have a very important number of elements to process in (Federico Peralta Schaffner explains it very well in its [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967083/what-is-the-best-practice-for-managing-java-8-streams-with-multiple-results/48967250?noredirect=1#comment84955161_48968150), thanks).

And in any other cases, I would keep the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @davidxxx there is `IntSummaryStatistics` that do more then one thing at a time, nothing wrong with that. A custom collector is more than fine here

Comment: @Eugene Right but could we not consider that collecting statistics is getting one thing : statistics ? Besides, it is a standard and provided out of the box.
The OP wants to collecting multiple instances of custom classes. I think that it is a different requirement.
About creating a custom collector, I disagree. The code of the Federico Peralta Schaffner answers that uses this way is interesting but requires more boiler plate code to perform something that
the original code of the OP performs in a straighter way.  I would use it but not in any case. I updated my answer.

Comment: @davidxxx that is *exactly* what the OP asked,  same thing via java-8 *or* a single pass, multiple results == custom collector, that the other answer has shown. You are correct, that wahtever the OP has in place is good, just that there *is* a way to do it in java-8...

Comment: @Eugene Indeed, it is "the way" in  java 8 streams. Always interesting to discuss with you. Thanks for your messages.

Comment: Hi David and @Eugene. I totally agree with both of you. I would use the approach given on the question, unless using a parallel stream proves being more useful and faster (which I'm yet to see, honestly). If using a parallel stream (or a sequential one if needed by style reasons or whatever other reason), then I'd go for a custom collector. In my answer I focused just on what the OP asked, which is how to do this with streams, and I left out the discussion about when it's convenient or inconvenient to go for one approach or the other, as this was properly discussed in this answer.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner Hello. Thanks for your feedback. You have very well addressed the requirement in Java 8. I updated mine with the parallelism use case as it may matter in some cases.   About "unless using a parallel stream proves being more useful and faster" , do you mean that you  benchmarked that without getting the expected result ?

Comment: @davidxxx honestly, I've never seen a parallel stream being faster than a sequential one.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner Wouh ! I didn't think of. I would think that high CPU consuming tasks performed during the stream operations could be a good use case.

Comment: @davidxxx that's the exact use case for parallel streams, the thing is that filtering and mapping (which are the most common tasks) are not high cpu. Most tasks are IO bound or cheap in terms of cpu usage, but it depends on the specific use case, it might happen that you need to do high CPU tasks as part of the pipeline. Besides, collecting is not CPU bound in most cases (we are moving things in memory and creating objects)...

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner  I get your point. To sum it, in theory, it could be faster but in the facts the suitable use case is rare. Thanks for your interesting feedback !

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that. To some extent, it's disappointing, because if streams had been designed to be sequential only, much more useful operations could have been added to the API. However, as streams need to also work in parallel, this imposes some restrictions and it introduces a lot of complexity. Only in the rare case when you want to parallelize CPU bound tasks you should use parallel streams. But this kind of tasks should be about 5% (rounding up and being generous)...

Answer (score 4):

The way to do things like this with streams is to use a custom collector. Suppose we define the following class:

```
public class Results {
    private final List<WebsiteModel> additionalWebsitesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<AreaModel> areaModels = new ArrayList<>();
    private final StringBuilder additionalWebsitesCsv = new StringBuilder();

    public void accumulate(WebsiteModel websiteModel) {
        additionalWebsitesList.add(websiteModel);
        areaModels.addAll(websiteModel.getAreas());
        additionalWebsitesCsv.append(websiteModel.getId());
    }

    public void combine(Results another) {
        additionalWebsitesList.addAll(another.additionalWebsitesList);
        areaModels.addAll(another.areaModels);
        additionalWebsitesCsv.append(another.additionalWebsitesCsv);
    }

    public List<WebsiteModel> getAdditionalWebsitesList() {
        return additionalWebsitesList;
    }

    public List<AreaModel> getAreaModels() {
        return areaModels;
    }

    public String getAdditionalWebsitesCsv() {
        return additionalWebsitesCsv.toString();
    }
}
```

With this `Results` class in place, you're ready to collect the results:

```
Results results = additionalWebsites.stream()
    .map(this::getWebsiteModel)
    .collect(Results::new, Results::accumulate, Results::combine);
```

This uses the [`Stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method. The first argument is a `Supplier` that creates the mutable object into which elements of the stream are to be accumulated via the accumulator provided in the second argument. The third argument is a merger that will only be used to combine partial results if the stream is parallel.

Comment: that's really inefficient code as per me. You actually need only one object of Result but in combiner you have to pass a new object all the time. In reality performance of this code should be very bad. @federico what's your say on that

Comment: @VinayPrajapati that's by contract, you must provide a combiner, even for sequential streams, though in this case it could be a dummy combiner or one that throws an exception. If the stream is parallel, the stream API automatically splits the elements into chunks and processes every chunk in parallel, so there must be a way to combine the results back together. On the contrary, for a very large number of elements, it's worth splitting, processing and combining. For few elements it's not worth mounting all the required infrastructure to process the stream pipeline in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

That code as Java 8 streams:

```
additionalWebsitesList = additionalWebsites.stream()
        .map(this::getWebsiteModel)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
areaModels = additionalWebsites.stream()
        .flatMap(w -> getWebsiteModel(w).getAreas().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
String additionalWebistesCsv = additionalWebsites.stream()
        .map(this::getWebsiteModel)
        .map(WebsiteModel::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking and was halfway through my answer ;). but it would be nice to state that you've avoided performing the logic in a single pass over the dataset to avoid side effects and thus one wouldn't want to go parallel with it.

Comment: Yes, But that means you are iterating through the list 3 times? Correct?

Comment: @Rado So what? The iteration itself takes no time. The problem would be if `getWebsiteModel()` is slow, then calling it thrice is bad. But as a simple getter, that takes no time either, so there is no downside to doing it 3 times.

Comment: This code is mor less just an example. I was curious if there is some regular way how to write this using streams, it looks like there is not;). Thank you very much for your reactions...